# R - Deriving short and long run effects in ARDL model

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, econometrics, ardl

I have an ARDL Unrestricted ECM that passes the Bounds test for cointegrtion. Now I want to calculate the short and long run estimates of the model, however I am unsure of how to do this in a multivariate model.

My UECM yields the following:

```
    Residuals:
      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max 
-0.035216 -0.007056 -0.000414  0.005722  0.034514 

Coefficients:
                      Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)          0.0189741  0.1170894   0.162  0.87155   
l.1.LogGPDI         -0.0449096  0.0156513  -2.869  0.00487 **
ld.1.LogGPDI        -0.1370236  0.1283551  -1.068  0.28791   
ld.2.LogGPDI         0.0186884  0.1249012   0.150  0.88132   
l.1.LogCorpTax      -0.0488639  0.0162154  -3.013  0.00316 **
l.1.LogUncertainty  -0.0164567  0.0146985  -1.120  0.26515   
l.1.gGDP             0.0033576  0.0012045   2.788  0.00619 **
l.1.PCE_Defl        -0.0028267  0.0015265  -1.852  0.06656 . 
l.1.LogNumPages      0.0464662  0.0261179   1.779  0.07780 . 
ld.1.LogCorpTax      0.0230720  0.0324518   0.711  0.47851   
ld.1.LogUncertainty -0.0289135  0.0161312  -1.792  0.07563 . 
ld.1.gGDP           -0.0013570  0.0007742  -1.753  0.08222 . 
ld.1.PCE_Defl        0.0058344  0.0025072   2.327  0.02167 * 
ld.1.LogNumPages    -0.0013915  0.0443357  -0.031  0.97501   
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.01099 on 118 degrees of freedom
  (3 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.3502,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.2786 
F-statistic: 4.893 on 13 and 118 DF,  p-value: 8.555e-07
```

I have been following Dave Gile's [post on ARDL estimation](https://davegiles.blogspot.com/2013/06/ardl-models-part-ii-bounds-tests.html), but I'm still unsure of how to derive the short and long run estimations given the multivariate case. Would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

For reference, I am using the R package Dynamac.

EDIT: I have figured out the long-run estimates, however I am still confused about the short-run coefficients. From what I understand, the short-run coefficients can be estimated with the differenced terms of the UECM equation with the inclusion of an error correction term. However, I am unsure how to calculate this error correction term.

Would someone be able to explain how to calculate this?

Answer (score 1):

Before estimating long-run equation you need to apply bounds cointegration test to see whether your data has long-run relationship or not.